# How do I use Firebase database Offline Capabilities

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a user when logged in creates a node in the firebase database, when the app crashes or the user logs out I want that node to be removed.
In the function `getCurrentOnlineUserInfo` I have embedded the `onDisconnect` function such that when the app is closed I want the `driverOffline` to be fired - in which I have `Geofire.removeLocation(currentFirebaseUser!.uid);` which will remove the node from the firebase.
In short I want `driverOffline` to be called only when the user disconnect.
So, far I have the code but not the logic.

```
  static void getCurrentOnlineUserInfo() async {
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

    String userId = firebaseUser!.uid;

    late DatabaseReference userRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('users').child('users/$userId');
   
    userRef.once().then((DatabaseEvent databaseEvent) {
      if (databaseEvent.snapshot.value != null) {
        userCurrentInfo = Users.fromSnapShot(databaseEvent.snapshot);
        // print('my name is ${userCurrentInfo.name}');
      }
    });

    await userRef.set(true);
    OnDisconnect onDisconnect = driversRef.onDisconnect();
    await onDisconnect.set(false);
    driverOffline(); // driver offline should be called only when the user is disconnected ?
  }

  static void driverOffline() async {
    Geofire.removeLocation(currentFirebaseUser!.uid); //remove this node
    rideRequestRef!.onDisconnect();

    await rideRequestRef!.remove();
    
    LocationManager().stop();
   
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase's `onDisconnect` handlers work by sending an instruction to the database when the client **is** connected, that the server then executes once it detects that the client has disconnected. There is no way to run from the client anymore in such a situation, as it has already disconnected.

So instead of this:

```
await userRef.set(true);
OnDisconnect onDisconnect = driversRef.onDisconnect();
await onDisconnect.set(false);
```

You should do this:

```
await userRef.set(true);
driversRef.onDisconnect().set(false);
```

The `set(false)` now runs on the server, once that detects that the client has disconnected (which may take a few minutes).

Same to remove `rideRequestRef` once the client has disconnected, you need to run this while the client *is* connected:

```
rideRequestRef!.onDisconnect().remove();
```

This send the instruction to the database server